# Is it possible that emulator runs out of memory?

Tags: android

When i run an app, which was before some time getting installed in the emulator (though it was showing force close due to some error), now shows 'Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE' in the console. I know it's a vague question, but i want to know, why or when it occurs? Thanks in advance.

Edit:Thanks for the replies. I guess it was showing this in mine, because I included a video file in the raw folder, which was consuming a lot of space. Thanks whatsoever!

Answer (score 3):

When you create an emulator device initially you need to specify some memory size. As far as my understanding goes, the app is first installed in the internal memory and then shifted to the sdcard. So yes it can run out of storage space, if your internal memory is filled. You may need to uninstall a few apps or create a new emulator. The same happens with android phones too if internal memory is filled.

Answer (score 1):

yes it could. That depends on the settings you choose during the emulator configuration trough the avd manager.